# How to add MBProgressHUD to a queue

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

no sign of networkI want to add MBProgressHUD to a queue, if the queue has MBProgressHUD show, do not add MBProgressHUD to this queue, if the queue is not MBProgressHUD display is added to the queue.

Chinese Version: 我想添加MBProgressHUD到一个队列中，如果这个队列中有MBProgressHUD显示，就不要添加MBProgressHUD到这个队列中，如果这个队列中没有MBProgressHUD显示则添加到这个队列中

Here is my code, but I can still see the display lots MBProgressHUD, and they are superimposed together, and will not disappear

```
+ (void)showErrorHUD:(id)target withText:(NSString *)text{
    MBProgressHUD *errorHud = nil;
    if ([target isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
       errorHud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[target view] animated:YES];
    }
    else if([target isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]){    
       errorHud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:target animated:YES];
    }
    errorHud.userInteractionEnabled = NO;// errorHud的下层视图可以响应
    errorHud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_red_x"]];
    errorHud.labelText = text;
    errorHud.labelColor = REDCOLOR;
    errorHud.customView = imageView;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        sleep(1);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[target isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]] ? target : [target view] animated:YES];
        });
    });   
}
```

In the phone without a network, APP will start when invoking multiple network interfaces, then performs the following methods to show no sign of network

```
[self showErrorHUD:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow withText:@"no network"];
```

Comment: What are you asking? It's completely unclear as to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Update your question. can not understand what you trying to do.

Comment: sorry everyone my English is poor, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

In the description of all is
https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  I've updated the question, Your answer seems not solve my problem.